# Handling deep linking with react navigation v5 authentication flow

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I want to access an authenticated screen from a deep-link using react navigation v5 with expo.
So I followed the [authentication flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) from react navigation and I ended with a start up navigator like that :

```
const StartupNavigator = (props: Partial<StackNavigatorProps>): ReactElement => {
    const {startUp} = useStartUp();

    const renderStacks = () => {
        if (startUp.isReady) {
            return <Stack.Screen name={Routes.HOME} component={BottomTabNavigator}/>;
        }
        if (startUp.isLoading) {
            return <Stack.Screen name={Routes.CHECK} component={CheckScreen}/>;
        }
        if (startUp.isBuilding) {
            return <Stack.Screen name={Routes.BUILD} component={BuildScreen}/>;
        }
        if (startUp.isAuthentifying) {
            return <Stack.Screen name={Routes.AUTH} component={AuthNavigator}/>;
        }
    };

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator {...props} headerMode={"none"}>
            {renderStacks()}
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

So I have 4 initial state :

1. **isReady** : The user is authenticated, and can access protected
   screens.
2. **isLoading**: First state when opening the app, check the app
   version..... then set the `isAuthentifying` state
3. **isAuthentifying**: The authentication navigator for registering, and login.
4. **isBuilding**: After authentication, fetch the user information, then set the state to `isReady`

Note, when opening the app, the state is set by default to `isLoading`

Then, I made an NavigationContainer following [this link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) for handling deep-linking

How to redirect to an authenticated screen passing by the authentication (note that I don't have an auto login process)

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am looking for the same

Comment: I went throught by storing the deeplink in a context, and then, when the user authenticate, apply the deeplink.

Comment: Can you send me an example of it please ?